# How to judge 2-demension array has value in C#?

Tags: c#

I am program with asp.net ,define two demension array,how to judge the array value null?

the array:

```
            #region inital Festival
            string[,] holidays = new string[13, 32];
            holidays[1, 1] = "元旦";
            holidays[2, 14] = "情人节";
            holidays[3, 8] = "妇女节";
            holidays[3, 12] = "植树节";
            holidays[4, 1] = "愚人节";
            holidays[5, 1] = "劳动节"
            holidays[5, 4] = "青年节";
            holidays[5, 12] = "护士节";
            holidays[5, 14] = "母亲节";
            holidays[5, 14] = "助残日";
            holidays[6, 1] = "国际儿童节";
            holidays[6, 5] = "环境保护日";
            holidays[6, 18] = "父亲节";
            holidays[6, 26] = "国际禁毒日";
            holidays[9, 10] = "教师节";                
            holidays[11, 23] = "感恩节";
            holidays[12, 1] = "艾滋病日";                
            holidays[12, 25] = "圣诞节";
            #endregion
```

There is my code:

```
string holiday = holidays[e.Day.Date.Month, e.Day.Date.Day];
                    DateTime LunDay = e.Day.Date;
                    LunDay ld = new LunDay();
                    if (holiday != string.Empty)
                    {
                        //If holiday value not null,add value
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If holiday is null,add tradition date in carlendar
                    }
```

I run the code but it aways add holiday and don't add tradition date,how to deal it.The string.Empty has no effect.

This is the whole code:

```
protected void portalCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            t.CurrentCulture = this.oldCulture;

            #region inital Festival
            string[,] holidays = new string[13, 32];
            holidays[1, 1] = "元旦";
            holidays[2, 14] = "情人节";
            holidays[3, 8] = "妇女节";
            holidays[3, 12] = "植树节";
            holidays[4, 1] = "愚人节";
            holidays[5, 1] = "劳动节";
            holidays[5, 4] = "青年节";
            holidays[5, 12] = "护士节";
            holidays[5, 14] = "母亲节";
            holidays[5, 14] = "助残日";
            holidays[6, 1] = "国际儿童节";
            holidays[6, 5] = "环境保护日";
            holidays[6, 18] = "父亲节";
            holidays[6, 26] = "国际禁毒日";
            holidays[7, 1] = "中共诞辰";
            holidays[8, 1] = "建军节";
            holidays[9, 10] = "教师节";
            holidays[10, 1] = "国庆节";
            holidays[11, 23] = "感恩节";
            holidays[12, 1] = "艾滋病日";
            holidays[12, 12] = "西安事变";
            holidays[12, 25] = "圣诞节";
            #endregion

            CalendarDay calDay = ((DayRenderEventArgs)e).Day;
            TableCell tableCell = ((DayRenderEventArgs)e).Cell;
            if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
            {
                e.Cell.Controls.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string holiday = holidays[e.Day.Date.Month, e.Day.Date.Day];
                    DateTime LunDay = e.Day.Date;
                    LunDay ld = new LunDay();
                    if (holiday != string.Empty)
                    {

                        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><font color=blue size=2>" + holiday + "</font>"));
                        //e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>" + ld.GetLunarCalendar(LunDay)));                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("null holiday"); 
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Response.Write(exception.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange enough, you have correct comments in your code, but incorrect implementation. Look at this:

```
if (holiday != string.Empty)
{
     //If holiday value not null,add value
}
```

Here you are saying 'if value not null' but in `if` condition you check value against empty string. Empty string is not the same as `null` value. You also need to add check against `null` to your code:

```
if (holiday != null && holiday != string.Empty)
{
     //If holiday value not null,add value
}
```

That will solve your problem.

BTW, there is also predefined method in framework to address this common scenario - `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, it checks string against null and empty value.

Comment: shorthand version - `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(holiday)){}`